# Passing parents props to slot in Vue,js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have in my application a `DocumenContainer` component which has multiple `ChartContainer` components. The `ChartContainer` has a slot in which I put various types of Charts (bar chart, Line Chart etc.). I would like to pass the data `isOuput` to the child component which is a slot

**ChartContainer** (simplified):

```html
<template>
    <div class="card-body">
        <slot v-slot="isOutput"></slot>
     </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() { 
            return {
                isOutput : false,
            }
        }
</script>
```

**DocumentContainer**:

```html
<chart-container title="Stats Model" v-slot="slotProps" :documentId="id">
  {{slotProps.isOuput}}
  <v-bar-chart  :docId="id"></v-bar-chart>
</chart-container>
```

I tried passing the `isOutput` to the parent (DocumentContainer) with `v-slot`. The problem right now is that I'm only able to print `{{slotProps.isOutput}}`. I would like to pass that `slotProps.isOutput` as a props to the `<v-bar-chart>` and

```html
 <v-bar-chart :isOuput="slotProps.isOutput" :docId="id"></v-bar-chart>
```

is giving me undefined in the bar-chart props.
Is there a simpler way than to pass the data to the parent and to the child? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is something to do with the `context`

It will work if you use `v-bind` instead

```
<v-bar-chart v-bind="{ isOutput: slotProps.isOutput, docId: id }"></v-bar-chart>
```

Example code

```js
const Component1 = {
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Component 1</h2>
    <button @click="isOutput = !isOutput">Toggle</button>
    <slot :isOutput="isOutput"></slot>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      isOutput: false,
    }
  }
};

const Component2 = {
  props: ['isOutput'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Component 2</h2>
    isOutput: {{String(isOutput)}}
  </div>
  `
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Component1,
    Component2
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <Component1>
    <template v-slot="slotProps">
        isOutput: {{String(slotProps.isOutput)}}
        <Component2 v-bind="{ isOutput: slotProps.isOutput }">
        </Component2>
    </template>
  </Component1>
</div>
```

Comment: You saved my day. Struggled to achieve this with different incorrect approaches with lack of proper understanding with scoped slots. Now I get it resolved it with this. Thanks.